# I uninstalled unity and my desktop went away, then reinstalled it and now sidebar and the top menu bar is missing

Tags: 14.04, unity, nautilus

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 'Trusty Tahr'
So after losing the sidebar and the menu bar I went to tty, reinstalled unity by using:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity

rebooted the system:

> sudo reboot

Still the side-bar is missing.
But one interesting thing is that when I log-in as a guest, the desktop has the sidebar and it works perfectly, just not in my superuser account. Why is that?

Edit 1:

Used the following commands as suggested by an answer:

> dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
>
> setsid unity

But the process got stuck at:

> Compiz (Core)- Info: Starting plugin: scale

I waited for an hour but nothing happened. And I still have a missing sidebar and running my programs through tty's. Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in to tty1.

Then run the following commands -

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

`setsid unity`

Comment: It is taking a really long time.
Currently stuck at:
> Compiz (Core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem... you say:

> when I log-in as a **guest**, the desktop has the sidebar and it works
>   perfectly, just not in my ***superuser*** account

This brings up two issues.

Does that mean you're logging in and running as root all the time? That shouldn't be necessary, and could lead to easily messing things up accidentally.

And whichever user account you're using, it sounds like something in it's home isn't configured right, especially if everything runs good as guest.

Try making a new user and logging in, does everything look good? If yes:

1. You could migrate to new user account, copying from your old home to the new one. Bring over config files for applications, skip the gnome/unity related stuff. Try a few at a time & log in to make sure everything still works, then copy more. Or
2. Try comparing your old home to the new user's home and see if there's something different messing up the desktop(but that could be like finding a needle in a needlestack)

Comment: Yeah I was root all the time. But I have migrated to different account(as you suggest here), and the GUI is good as new. I've started learning more about Unix that I've ever known before, with the tty's. I'm glad I screwed up my 'unity'.

Comment: That's good news, if it worked & was helpful feel free to check-mark / select /upvote the answer.

Comment: Don't have enough reps for that. :|

Comment: Hmmm, it should let you at least select / check-mark a correct answer... maybe now?

Comment: d'oh, that's the other guy's....

Comment: Sorry bro, that's the standard solution and it works. I had already tried migration before reading your solution. Thanks but your's not a standard solution. I'll give you a vote-up, when I am eligible.

Comment: Your Q even says that one didn't work... hmm

Comment: I must've forgot to update it. Sorry.